# rails runnerで作られたバッチのspecによるテスト方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Railsプロジェクト上で、rails runnerを使って、以下にバッチを作ったとします。

lib/tasks/hogehoge.rb

このファイルをrspecを使ってテストしたい場合、

- どのパスに
- どうやって

記述をしたらよいでしょうか、ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

僕だったらロジックの大半をクラスメソッドに書いて、そのクラスをテストします。
テスト容易性を重視した実装にする、というアプローチです。

```
# lib/tasks/hogehoge.rb
Hoge.do_something

# app/models/hoge.rb
class Hoge < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.do_something
    # ...
  end
end

# spec/models/hoge_spec.rb
describe Hoge do
  describe '::do_something' do
    it 'does something' do
      expect(Hoge.do_something).to blah blah...
    end
  end
end
```

ちなみに[Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp/)の第10章でもこのアプローチが紹介されています。
ご参考までに。